# How to write a function that relies on a database variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
  SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
  FROM sys.columns c
      JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
  WHERE c.name LIKE '%MyName%'
```

I would like the code above to be put the TVF in a tools database, and call it from where-ever on the server and search the database of my choosing.

Is this even possible, would I have to use SP with the exec statement ? 
My concern is that I have other frequently used queries that I would also like to store in this but they are much longer...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use a variable for a database is to use `dynamic sql`, which is not possible in a TVF.   You could only do it with a stored procedure.

Comment: Or use OpenQuery. :)

Comment: MSDN says that OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments, which jives with my experience with it.    Am I missing something?

Comment: No I meant you could use OpenQuery to execute your created string. Still can't execute it in a function.